# How to send whatsapp message via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I would like to know if there is something to send a whatsapp message using javascript or something I was searching but I did not find any new post. This is not for any special purpose. I found this but it only works if you have whatsapp web. I was thinking on clicking on a link to send a default message to a default number

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1111111111">Send Message</a>
```

Answer (score 17):

Just make use of this function in web browser to get it running as you want.

> **Note**: You need to run the code manually through browser console with an opened conversation in WhatsApp
> (web version).

```
function sendMessage(message){
  const mainEl = document.querySelector('#main')
  const textareaEl = mainEl.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]')

  if(!textareaEl) {
    throw new Error('There is no opened conversation')
  }

  textareaEl.focus()
  document.execCommand('insertText', false, message)
  textareaEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }))

  setTimeout(() => {
    (mainEl.querySelector('[data-testid="send"]') || mainEl.querySelector('[data-icon="send"]')).click()
  }, 100)
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/Matt-Fontes/SendScriptWhatsApp/blob/main/shrekSendScript.js

Comment: This one is really working. I'll try to automate it using puppeteer. Thanks for the codes...

Comment: @RenanCoelho checa seu email

Comment: Can we send an image file taken from a html form to WhatsApp using JavaScript?

Answer (score 8):

I find this way is a better way to send a msg to WhatsApp unknowing number.

[Demo](https://omar-bakhsh.github.io/Whatsapp_Bot_javascript/index.html)

```js
// github: omar-bakhsh
function send_handle() {
  const num = document.getElementById("number").value;
  const msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
  const name = document.getElementById("name").value;

  const win = window.open(`https://wa.me/${num}?text=I%27m%20api%20msg%20hello%20${name}%20friend%20${msg}`, '_blank');
  // win.focus();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>whatsapp send app </h3>
  <h6>add number without space like 17272912606 not <strike>+1 (727) 2912606 </strike></h6>
  <input id="number" type="numric" placeholder="phone 966506666666">
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name">
  <input id="msg" type="text" placeholder="type msg">
  <button onclick="send_handle()">send</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**On the [WhatsApp developers hub](https://business.whatsapp.com/developers/developer-hub)**, they demonstrated a walkthrough guide on how to opt-in for a developer account on meta, and create an app so can make api calls if you want to use WhatsApp *programmatically*,

Short version:

- Register as a Meta Developer
- Enable two-factor authentication for your account
- Create a Meta App: Go to developers.facebook.com > My Apps > Create App.
- Select the "Business" type and follow the prompts on your screen.
- Scroll down to find the "WhatsApp" product and click Set up.
- Select an existing Business Manager, if you don't the wizard will guide you to create one.
- Next screen will show you a demo.
- If you need a listener when your number receive a message or reply, you should register webhooks.
- Add your phone number to use it programmatically. and it shouldn't be connected with WhatsApp at all, neither personal or business.

for more details follow the getting started guide:

> https://business.whatsapp.com/developers/developer-hub

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1111111111&text=Hi">Send Message</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatsapp dosen't support sending messages from the PC. Every message has to come from a Phone. Whatsapp web is just redirecting the messages to your phone wich is then sending the message. If you use their api you only can let users send a message to any number via Whatsapp using their phone. To predetermine the message use:

> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappphonenumber&text=urlencodedtext

more: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251

Answer (score 1):

A script can run in the browser console and send the same message multiple times. When you want to execute it, just open chat of the person to which you want to send messages.

Here is the code:

```
function sendMessage(message) {
  const mainEl = document.querySelector("#main");
  const textareaEl = mainEl.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]');

  if (!textareaEl) {
    throw new Error("There is no opened conversation");
  }

  textareaEl.focus();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, message);

  setTimeout(() => {
    // Simulate pressing the Enter key
    const enterKeyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      key: "Enter",
      code: "Enter",
      keyCode: 13,
      which: 13,
    });
    textareaEl.dispatchEvent(enterKeyEvent);

    setTimeout(() => {
      const sendButton =
        mainEl.querySelector('[data-testid="send"]') ||
        mainEl.querySelector('[data-icon="send"]');
      if (sendButton) {
        sendButton.click();
      } else {
        console.error("Send button not found");
      }
    }, 100);
  }, 1000); // 1-second delay before sending the next message
}

// Example: Send the same message on new lines with a delay of 1 second between messages
const message = "Here goes your message";
const numberOfTimes = 50;

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    sendMessage(message);
  }, i * 2000); // Delay each message by i * 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do it with HTML link. Whatsapp has no official API. But you can find (or write it by yourself) some script to emulate user actions on the site web.whatsapp.com. For example, [this one](https://gist.github.com/yask123/d085d4b7a486d00dd103) (I did not test it).