# how to change an innerHTML on Whatsapp web?

Tags: javascript, automation, whatsapp, web-extension

I was working on a script to mention members on WhatsApp groups by JS. All the work stopped when I wanted to change the innerHTML using the .innerHTML property to place a mention HTML block in it instead of writing the names of the members then focus the elemnt and clik on the contact name that pops up.

## HTML of the input textbox on WA web

```
<div 
    class="fd365im1 to2l77zo bbv8nyr4 gfz4du6o ag5g9lrv bze30y65 kao4egtt"
    style="max-height: 7.35em; 
    user-select: text; 
    white-space: 
    pre-wrap; word-break: 
    break-word;" 
    role="textbox"
    spellcheck="false" 
    title="Type a message" 
    data-testid="conversation-compose-box-input" 
    data-tab="10"
    data-lexical-editor="true" 
    contenteditable="true">

    <!-- the inner HTML -->
    <p class="selectable-text copyable-text iq0m558w">Test text</p>
    
</div>
```

## JS to change its inner HTML

```
var typespace = document
.querySelector('div.fd365im1.to2l77zo.bbv8nyr4.gfz4du6o.ag5g9lrv.bze30y65.kao4egtt');
```

I have trying accessing the DOM by many ways and all the ways go to Rome and return the right address of the DOM but sruprisingly trying to

`typespace.innerHTML = '<p class="selectable-text copyable-text iq0m558w" dir="ltr"><span class="selectable-text copyable-text o0rubyzf" data-app-text-template="​201144292107@c.us​" data-lexical-text="true">@Abdo Eid</span><span class="selectable-text copyable-text" data-lexical-text="true"> </span></p>`

doesn't work at all. I noticed that after changing it manally from the HTML and trys to use innerHTML it works as expected.

OS: windows 10    lang: JS    browser: Chrome, Firefox both at latest versions

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer, but I think what you are trying to do is dynamically place some text in the whatsapp message container to then send it. Unfortunatelly to you this is a little more complicated, as whatsapp does some deeper stuff to send the messages and all this stuff. I don't know how it works but I do know it's way more complicated than that, so good luck to you for trying to do that! Sorry if my comment wasn't very useful, but I just wanted to warn you that you are entering a more complicated territory than you think

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. I have already handled it using events as WA does but it is drastically slower than what may I find (workaround or so).

Comment: I'm glad you found a way to do it. Even though it's slower, it probably is the best, at least without a huge amount of work

Comment: did you search before asking this question? [This works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465009/13006545)

Comment: @Traidos Yes, I have searched a lot. In the question I have stated that I don't want to add more clicks to the steps of the script.