# Change in div content not update in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I´m trying to make a chrome extension what working in whatsapp web, but something very strange is happening. When trying to change a div content who has a P and SPAN tags, exactly the place of text to change, is happening what does not update the DOM on the screen, even though the command runs without error. Noting that I already tried with innerHTML, innerText and textContent properties. It even worked in tests in the W3schools try, where the text change appears. What can it be?

```
`document.addEventListener('keyup', 
    function(event) {
        const clickedElem = event.target
        console.log(clickedElem.tagName);

        if (clickedElem.contentEditable === "true") {
            console.log('is here');
            console.log(clickedElem.innerText);
            let x = clickedElem.innerText;
            if (x === 'xxx') {
                console.log('match');
                $(clickedElem).find('span').innerText='New text';
                console.log(clickedElem.innerText);

            }
        }
    })`

`
```

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the HTML code?

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you get the input text as you did `let x = clickedElem.innerText` then you will edit the variable values to replace the wanted string `x = x.replaceAll("xxx", "New text")`.

Then, as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243154/how-to-send-whatsapp-message-via-javascript) use `textareaEl.focus()` then `document.execCommand('insertText', false, x) // <= here goes your variable`

Comment: I don't actually want to send a message, but just change the text that appears in the span. There is an extension, Magical that does this!

Comment: There is a place in the answer that just change the input text:   `textareaEl.focus()`
then `document.execCommand('insertText', false, message)`

Comment: PS: readMessage (??)

Comment: `readMessage` is the text that you read from your code.

As i explained in my answer, you can read the message first `let x = clickedElem.innerText` and then change the `x` value using `x = x.replaceAll("xxx", "New text")`

Comment: ok Luís HNriqu, I'm analyzing this fragment [*textareaEl*]

Comment: Edited the answer, if this is indeed what you want, please give me a upvote and mark as right answer :)

Comment: Luís HNrique  - one more thing: the example mentioned uses [insertText] which inserts in front, but I need it to replace the existing text with the new text. Has as?